# "Comparant" or "comparants": Which one is correct? And why?

Tags: accord, participe-présent, gérondif

So here are my two sentences:

> Il démontre l'efficacité des approches proposées **en les comparant** avec les autres approches.
>
> Il démontre l'efficacité des approches proposées **en les comparants** avec les autres approches.

Which one is correct and why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Il démontre l'efficacité des approches proposées **en les comparant** avec les autres approches.

Nous sommes en présence d'un **gérondif**. Le gérondif explicite le verbe, soit en exprimant une action simultanée à celle exprimée par le verbe, soit en exprimant une circonstance liée à l'action.  Il est toujours **invariable**, il est toujours précédé de *en*. Ce *en* a perdu tout effet de préposition et n'est qu'une indication du gérondif.
Dans la phrase donnée « En comparant » explicite « il démontre ».

Le seul cas où on **accorde** [radical du verbe + -ant]  c'est quand il s'agit d'un **adjectif verbal**, celui-ci fonctionne comme un adjectif :

> Il fit chauffer l'eau sur les braises fumantes.

La troisième sorte de mot en **-ant** est le **participe présent**.
Le participe présent n'est jamais précédé de *en*, il qualifie un nom ou un pronom. Il est invariable.

> Cette démonstration comparant les deux approches est très intéressante.

Dans cette dernière phrase « comparant » qualifie « Cette démonstration ».

Finissons en comparant sur une même racine verbale :

> - Il a terminé sa démonstration en me convainquant.
> - Convainquant son auditoire, il fut largement applaudi.
> - Cette démonstration est convaincante.*

<sub>* Noter la modification orthographique du radical pour l'adjectif.</sub>